# Error with Eclipse and Android API Level 22

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I have encountered an issue when attempting to use Eclipse with Android SDK.

Upon starting Eclipse, I encountered the following error message:

> Error: Error parsing C:\Users\CHINTA
>   VAMSHI\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Another user is experiencing the same issue as me over here:

[Android SDK Error when loading the SDK:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418443/android-sdk-error-when-loading-the-sdk)

It seems to be only affecting Eclipse users who has installed Android API Level 22.

May I know if there is a solution to this problem?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418443/android-sdk-error-when-loading-the-sdk?lq=1