# Android SDK Error when loading the SDK:

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1mBnz.png

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started/30440239#30440239

Comment: Does stackoverflow.com apply OCR to images? If not, it would have been nice to add the precise error message in text for easier search.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Deleting**(uninstalling) the package **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image** available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) resolves this problem.

For details see this link - [Error Loading the sdk when eclipse is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started#30439524)

Comment: Thanks! Update: after release of 23 removing the same package from API23 resolves this error again

Comment: Did not work for me. Deleted said package and error message persists.

Comment: @Steve try re-starting your IDE after deleting packages.

Comment: In API 26, **two** packages need to deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983661/2597758

Answer (score 35):

I had the same error message but one of the solutions suggested was defining my application to work under `API level 19`. Really that wasn´t an option for me, so my solution was **deleting the packages** from the `API 22`:

- **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image**
- **Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image**

[image]

Comment: Same is the case with API 23.

Comment: True. Going back to API 19 is not an option, since Google's email message from **2018/08/02** specifically requires targetSdkVersion **API 26** and higher. In my case, this error started as soon as I installed API 26 in addition to API 8.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem too when trying to install the Android SDK for libgdx. I solved it by deleting every package from the "Android 5.1.1 (API 22)" in the Android SDK Manager except for Documentation for Android SDK, SDK Platform, Samples for SDK, ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google API's and Sources for Android SDK.

[image]

This solved the error for me. I guess it was a problem witht he other packages. I hope this helps :)

/EDIT:
This sadly also resulty in libgdx not recognizing my API22 version. Not really sure why exactly, since it does successfully show up in the Android settings in Eclipse. :/
So if somebody has a proper fix I would be interested aswell ^^

Answer (score 4):

I got rid of error by commenting out **all** `<d:skin />` element on two files:

- C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
- C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml

like this

```
<!--<d:skin>AndroidWearSquare</d:skin>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get rid of the error by uninstalling both wear images from API 22 package in SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to delete **Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image** (under *Android 5.1.1 (API 22)*).

But my emulator still won't start!. Bring on Android Studio...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all latest Android Wear and TV emulators have this problem. Only deleting all of them solved this problem for me. Just go through all of them in SDK manager and delete'em all - should helps. In the case you need Wear and TV emulators - seems now there is no other way than using Android Studio for development. C'est la vie.